# Tokenizing a text box with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to build a "tokenizer" of sorts that will analyze a text box using javascript as I type into it, and respond with various behaviors based on what was entered.

Then I realized I have NO CLUE what I am doing. . . Has this been done? I've searched for a bit on jQuery tokenization and only found something that related to a pre-defined list. The behavior I am aiming for is akin to facebook's "tagging" mechanic, where you are typing, then can use a special symbol to mark a "token".

Can this even be done in HTML/javascript?

Comment: The "Tags" field on the Stack Overflow "Edit question" page is proof that it can be done.  :-)  If you're looking for code to do it, searching for "jQuery Tag editor" or similar could be useful.

Comment: This can be done. Listen to KeyPress and search the text for the token. E.g. '#'. What happends next depends on your specification. In case of a hashtag the following word (up to the next whitespace) will be your token.

Comment: Google for "jquery tags input"... The first link is http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/ looks like that what you want.

Comment: That is a lot like what I want, but I want to insert tokens alongside Non Token input. Is that possible?